# java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) while reading an image from an URL

Tags: java, android

I need help, please. I'm still errors in this part, and I've tried to run but I still have the error.
when I load images from URL, I have this issue:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:313)
    at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:211)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1242)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1170)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:22)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:14)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:43)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:96)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:61)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:303)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:398)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:118)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:150)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:141)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:48)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:96)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:61)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:303)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:273)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:445)
```

I need help. This is my Java class. I don't where is the error. I also added it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

public class But1_room extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "But1_room";

//Vars
private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_but1_room);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

    initImageBitmaps();

}

private void initImageBitmaps()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "initImageBitmaps: preparing bitmaps");

    mImageUrls.add("https://www.google.com/search?q=habitaciones&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimgMjLjL3eAhXEVN8KHYntAwEQ_AUIDigB&biw=1364&bih=666#");
    mNames.add("Habitación 1");

    mImageUrls.add("https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hotel-atriumpalacebarcelona.com%2Fwp-content%2Fblogs.dir%2F576%2Ffiles%2Fdobleslider%2Fhotel_atriumpalace_doble_5.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hotel-atriumpalacebarcelona.com%2Fhabitaciones%2F&docid=h_vcbHpKWnJ6rM&tbnid=QNEGeBRhg3XQvM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwi_wdXMjL3eAhViS98KHf_0BJQQMwhBKAMwAw..i&w=3000&h=2000&bih=666&biw=1364&q=habitaciones&ved=0ahUKEwi_wdXMjL3eAhViS98KHf_0BJQQMwhBKAMwAw&iact=mrc&uact=8");
    mNames.add("Habitación 2");

    mImageUrls.add("https://www.google.com/search?q=habitaciones&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimgMjLjL3eAhXEVN8KHYntAwEQ_AUIDigB&biw=1364&bih=666#");
    mNames.add("Habitación 3");

    mImageUrls.add("https://www.google.com/search?q=habitaciones&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimgMjLjL3eAhXEVN8KHYntAwEQ_AUIDigB&biw=1364&bih=666#");
    mNames.add("Habitación 4");

    mImageUrls.add("https://www.google.com/search?q=habitaciones&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimgMjLjL3eAhXEVN8KHYntAwEQ_AUIDigB&biw=1364&bih=666#");
    mNames.add("Habitación 5");

    mImageUrls.add("https://www.google.com/search?q=habitaciones&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimgMjLjL3eAhXEVN8KHYntAwEQ_AUIDigB&biw=1364&bih=666#");
    mNames.add("Habitación 6");

    initRecyclerView();
}

private void initRecyclerView()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview.");
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
}
```

Could you please help me in this part.|?

Comment: on visiting the url in your code...it redirects me to a webpage instead of the image. try providing the image url. Try something like https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png

Comment: you just gave the URL of website. Not specific image. You should open that image and then copy URL of that image and paste it in your code.

Comment: Now, I have this problem: I still have the same problem. 
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
I loaded your image. @divaPrajapati09

Comment: @habner add https:// before url and let me know back

Comment: I added this link and I still have the same problem: mImageUrls.add("http://www.sagiturviajes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/dubai3-copia.jpg");
        mNames.add("Habitación 1");
@divaPrajapati09